# " ListView " has been removed from react native

Tags: react-native

My emulator says that

> ListView has been removed from react native

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it's removed since March 2017 release and you cannot use it any more.**

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html),

> No more ListViews or DataSources, stale rows, ignored bugs, or excessive memory consumption - with the latest React Native March 2017 release candidate (0.43-rc.1) you can pick from the new suite of components what best fits your use-case, with great perf and feature sets out of the box:

You have other options like,

1. `<FlatList>`
2. `<SectionList>`
3. `<VirtualizedList>`