# React Native Error - ListView has been removed from ReactNative

Tags: react-native, listview

All,

Recently i have updated my project to 0.60.5, I am solving errors one by one, I am getting a issue stating, ListView has been removed from ReactNative.

I have removed all the ListView references from project, cleared cache, Run the Yarn again. But still getting the same error.

[image: 0.60]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [" ListView " has been removed from react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351668/listview-has-been-removed-from-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
import {ListView} from 'react-native';

<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
/>
```

with

```
import {FlatList} from 'react-native';

<FlatList
  data={this.state.dataSource}
  renderItem={({rowData}) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
/>
```

Comment: I do the changes and there are no references of ListView in the project, Seems there is a refrence in native-base which is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

> No more ListViews or DataSources, stale rows, ignored bugs, or
>   excessive memory consumption - with the latest React Native March 2017
>   release candidate (0.43-rc.1) you can pick from the new suite of
>   components what best fits your use-case, with great perf and feature
>   sets out of the box:

You have other options like,

```
<FlatList>
<SectionList>
<VirtualizedList>
```

Find more info here : [React native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html)

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351668/listview-has-been-removed-from-react-native)